# JavaScript Undefined index / Incorrect array length

Tags: javascript, arrays

Getting something very odd happening with an array in my code. I have made a JS fiddle to demonstrate (you will have to open up your browsers console to see the logs).

I have also provided an image high lighting whats happening.

I would like some explanation as to why this might be happening.

Basically, an array of size 3 only shows 2 of the elements within the array. When i console log the array.length, it shows as 3, however upon opening the object only 2 elements are visible, something doesn't seem right here to me.

EDIT: I used the console log simply to show what was happening. My real issue is I cant access this 3rd element in the code, and I need to.

Please see the JS fiddle & image attached.

https://jsfiddle.net/ysf2o39f/

```
console.log('Init');
var arr = []; // Array of objects
var obj = {}; // Dummy object
// Fill array
arr.push(obj);
arr.push(obj);
arr.push(obj);
// Log
console.log('Before pop: ');
console.log(arr);
console.log('Length: ' + arr.length);
// Pop array
arr.pop();
// Log
console.log('After pop: ');
console.log(arr);
console.log('Length: ' + arr.length);
```

[image: Image of the issue]

Comment: Try executing this one by one individually in the console and the issue will likely disappear.

Comment: I used the console log simply to show what was happening. My real issue is I cant access this 3rd element in the code, and I need to.

Comment: Try to log a _copy_ of the array into the console using `arr.slice()` and you will see the behaviour is now corrected. This has to do with how the console stores and displays data, in this case both are displaying the modified array.

Comment: Yes, when you access in the console to the details of the array, it is modified and it shows the modified array, as @somethinghere said

Comment: You will not have problems in your development if you try to access third element. Your code is not selecting in the console.

Comment: Your *only* issue in this sample is the console. Programmatic access should work just fine. If it doesn't, provide an actual representative sample.

Comment: I can't provide the actual example unfortunately. Its part of quite a large application with various classes.

Comment: But you have no problem accessing the third element in the provided example, right? In that case this is all we can do for you.

Comment: Then you'll have to debug your large application and possibly reduce it to a representative sample. We can't tell you what's wrong with your application with the given code, since there is nothing wrong with the code given.

Comment: OK. That is understandable, I'll make work on reducing it.